# cakePHP v2, TextHelper::autoLinkUrls, preg_replace_callback(), Error: Requires argument 2

Tags: cakephp, preg-replace-callback

Has anybody had trouble with using the autoLinkUrls function in cakePHP v2.0?

It's giving me this error:

```
Warning (2): preg_replace_callback() [function.preg-replace-callback]: Requires argument 2, 'View::_linkBareUrl', to be a valid callback [CORE\Cake\View\Helper\TextHelper.php, line 128]
```

Comment: Sounds like a version mismatch - the function `_linkBareUrl` was removed about version 2.1. State what version of cake you're using, and check that there are no modfications to your Cake folder (e.g. compared to https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.1.0/lib/Cake/View/Helper/TextHelper.php).

Comment: Thanks AD7six, I'm running version 2.0.0, I copied over the TextHelper from 2.0.0 but it's still giving the same error.  Any other thoughts?  Should I upgrade to the latest cake version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Don't call none-static methods statically

[The code](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.0.0/lib/Cake/View/Helper/TextHelper.php#L111-L132) for the function you're referring to is:

```
public function autoLinkUrls($text, $htmlOptions = array()) {
    $this->_linkOptions = $htmlOptions;
    $text = preg_replace_callback(
        '#(?<!href="|src="|">)((?:https?|ftp|nntp)://[^\s<>()]+)#i',
        array(&$this, '_linkBareUrl'),
        $text
    );
    return preg_replace_callback(
        '#(?<!href="|">)(?<!http://|https://|ftp://|nntp://)(www\.[^\n\%\ <]+[^<\n\%\,\.\ <])(?<!\))#i',
        array(&$this, '_linkUrls'),
        $text
    );
}
```

It's not a static method but based upon the error message - `$this` is a view instance. That means you're probably calling it statically i.e.:

```
echo TextHelper::autoLinkUrls($foo);
```

This is wrong, don't do that - instead use it as designed:

```
echo $this->Text->autoLinkUrls($foo);
```

### Your version of cake is *old*

While it's not relevant to the problem at hand, 2.0.0 is two years old. There have been 6 patch releases since then and it would be wise to update to the lastest of them ([2.0.6](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/tree/2.0.6) at the time of writing. Bug-fix/patch release have no functional changes at all). Upgrading to a more recent minor releas (2.1.x, 2.2.x, 2.3.x) will introduce new functionality but also the need to review your application and possibly adapt to introduced/removed api/functional changes.

Comment: Right on thanks AD7six, I tried it your way and it wasn't turning it into a link (but wasn't getting the error also) so I thought I was going down the wrong path.  But I realized it was something else.  Your answer got it working, thanks for your help.